# Versioning in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Had a quick question regarding versioning in Web Api 2.0.

I've developed an entirely RESTful API, however I have 2 controllers of the same name.

I've put them in diff namespaces according to separate folders.
(E.g. v1 and v2 folders).

[image]

I've also configured the correct routing using the normal NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.
So up until now everything is working correctly.

I had a question however...is it possible to *still have versioning* for the Emails controller *even if I put*  EmailsController on the Root level?

E.g.

> Controllers/v1/EmailControllers
>
> Controllers/EmailsControllers

Would this still be possible?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I have not used the `RoutePrefix` attribute because I kept on receiving errors on my `RouteConstraint`.

I've decorated my action methods with the following (which seems a bit redundant because they essentially have the same Namespace):

`[Route("api/{apiVersion1:ApiVersion1Constraint(v1)}/emails/LogEmails", Name = "LogEmailsRoute_1")]`

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried with [ApiVersion] attribute

```
    [ApiVersion( "1.0", Deprecated = true )]    
    [ApiVersion( "2.0" )]
    [ApiVersion( "3.0" )]
    [Route( "api/v{version:apiVersion}/email" )]
    public class Email2Controller : Controller {

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "Email  v2!";

    [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion( "3.0" )]
    public string GetV3() => "Email v3!";

    }
```

Comment: I've managed to solve this some time ago using a Route Controller. But thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RoutePrefix` attribute on controller.
More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My first intention was to use the `RoutePrefix` attribute at the controller level. Although, I received numerous errors stating my route constraint did not work. I will however check this link.