# WebApi versioning a single controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am just starting to get into `WebApi` and what I am trying to understand is if you can have 1 controller that handles multiple versions.

so instead of having a `v1`/`v2` folders where v2 has a copy of the controller in v1 but the logic in v2 is different from v1

Can you have 1 controller that what will handle all api versions?

I have seen reference to `[APiVersion(...)]` attribute on a controller but when I try to implement what I thought is right nothing gets called

Example:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/login")]
public class LoginController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("login/{username}/{password}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(LoginResult))]
    public LoginResult GetLoginInfo(string username, string password)
    {
        //v1 logic
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("login/{username}/{password}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(LoginResult))]
    public LoginResult GetLoginInfo2(string username, string password)
    {
        //v2 logic
    }
}
```

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073836/versioning-in-web-api-2) as a reference but it does not seem to work. Is using actions the way to solve this?

Ideally I would just like to be able to change the version number anywhere that it gets called instead of changing the action name but I don't know if that's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to just make sure the routes do not clash by putting the version directly in the route of the single controller.

```
public class LoginController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/v1/login/{username}/{password}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(LoginResult))]
    public LoginResult GetLoginInfo(string username, string password) {
        //v1 logic
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/v2/login/{username}/{password}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(LoginResult))]
    public LoginResult GetLoginInfo2(string username, string password) {
        //v2 logic
    }
}
```

Now if a new version is added, just include that version number in the route.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/v3/login/{username}/{password}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(LoginResult))]
public LoginResult GetLoginInfo3(string username, string password) {
    //v3 logic
}
```

Keep it Simple...